# Virus culture in artificial/synthetic medium

Tags: virology, cell-culture, medium

I am looking for a publication/paper in a well a circulated magazine/journal/government study on growing virus culture in synthetic or artificial medium. I have found this link on SARS Cov 2 being cultured in  artificial saliva, but are there any sources handy?

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/22221751.2020.1777906?scroll=top&needAccess=true

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What is your "goal"? The linked paper is not "culturing" viruses in artificial saliva, but rather looking at viral survival (aka decay rate) in that medium.

Comment: In the linked study they didn't grow it in artificial saliva or artificial culture medium (DMEM) - it was grown in cells (as viruses need to be) and then aerosolized for stability testing in the saliva or medium.  In some manner all media used for growing any cells and viruses are artificial - we make and purify compounds that are then mixed to make the final solution. The exact compositions of these solutions are not found in nature at all, but were derived experimentally by cell culture researchers.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Apologies, I should have gone through the whole article. The other day I was having a discussion with a colleague (also a buddy from college) on whether viruses can be cultured outside living cells i.e in a synthetic or artificial medium, under the right stimulation. Is it possible? (We were discussing on some vector vaccine)